# Word Separator for Python

Tags: python

```
    my_string = input("Enter words. ")
    i = 0
    result = ()
    for c in my_string:
        if c.isupper() and i > 0:
            result += ( )
            result += c.lower()
        else:
            result += c
        i += 1

    print result
```

I've been trying to make a word separator for python except I'm having a lot of trouble with it, I've found a similar question on StackOverflow except they don't use an input statement which is what I'm trying to figure out. I have this to go off of, I just need to make it to where there's an input statement involved to ask the user to input whatever they cluster of words they want to be separated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `result += ( )` does nothing and `result += c.lower()` should throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: I'm sure that if I replace the input statement I've tried to place in the code with "PurpleCows" for example, it will offer a good output. But I'll your comment now.

Comment: What is the output supposed to be?

Comment: It's supposed to take an input and put spaces between the cluster of words that are inputted. For example, you enter "PurpleCowsAreNice" and the output is "Purple Cows Are Nice"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
Iteration with `yield`:

```
In [156]: def split(string):
     ...:     for c in string:
     ...:         if c.isupper():
     ...:             yield ' '
     ...:         yield c
     ...:             

In [157]: ''.join(split("PurpleCowsAreNice"))
Out[157]: ' Purple Cows Are Nice'
```

---

**Option 2**
`re.sub` with reference groups:

```
In [159]: re.sub('([A-Z])', r' \1', "PurpleCowsAreNice")
Out[159]: ' Purple Cows Are Nice'
```

For simplicity, I've allowed both methods to yield a result with leading spaces, but you could just as easily remove them with `str.strip`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But is there a way I could make it include an input statement so the program asks the user what cluster of words they want to enter, and then space them out? Sorry if I wasn't clear about that before, I very much appriciate the help!

Comment: @BlakeMcLaughlin Here's a good [starting point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)... You should be able to fit that into your program no problems.